# throttle functions return(...args),return function(...args)

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, arguments, throttling, args

Hello i'm trying to learn the concept of throttling,i've read some articles and "kinda" got the hang of it (the concept at least) but there is one thing i can't figure out when reading these functions and is the part where u return a function with the "arguments" for example in these functions i found:

```
  const throttleFunction = (func, delay) => {
        let prev = 0;
        return (...args) => {
            let now = new Date().getTime();
            if (now - prev > delay) {
                prev = now;
                return func(...args);
            }
        }
    }
    
    const throttle = (func, limit) => {
        let inThrottle
        return function() {
          const args = arguments
          const context = this
          if (!inThrottle) {
            func.apply(context, args)
            inThrottle = true
            setTimeout(() => inThrottle = false, limit)
          }
        }
      }
```

i don't get what the

```
return (...args) => {
    
            return func(...args);
        }
```

does
same in the other one

```
 const args = arguments
   func.apply(context, args)
```

in fact i'm having some troubles tryng to use them some times i get them to work some times i don't especially when i have to pass parameters to the function i want to throttle

when i have a single button i usually do

```
<button onclick="throttleFunction(some_function,1500)">Click me</button>
```

and it works

but when i have to pass something like the "this" i can't get it
let's say i have some divs
i do

```
const func = (thhis) => {
 console.log(thhis);
}
const x = throttleFunction(func,2500);

<div class="abc" onclick="x(this)"> something </div>
<div class="abc" onclick="x(this)"> something </div>
<div class="abc" onclick="x(this)"> something </div>
```

and it doesn't work the function gets called every time i click on the div...

can someone explain me ?

Comment: I made this js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9hoant7d/ To test your statement `and it doesn't work the function gets called every time i click on the div...`, and that doesn't seem to be true to me on the jsfiddle. It seems to be throttling it just fine.

Comment: what does the `window.x` does ?

Comment: makes sure the `x` function is available for when you put it in the html `onclick=""` area

Comment: ok...i found out why this wasn't working cuz i was using an arrow function and it didn't worked when i passed the "this" i've rewritten as `function(..args)` instead of `(...args) =>{}`  anywai i still can't figure out what the `return (...args) => {
    
            return func(...args);
        }` sentence means

Comment: Regarding your last comment ... you are dealing with [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). This is how within this code example the arguments are received and passed. Of course the implementation of `throttleFunction` does not take `this` context into account, which means that just plain functions, but never context sensitive methods, can be turned safely into a throttled variations of themself.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of throttling is literally to avoid subsequent function calls to be executed for a limited amount of time.

> 1. Say hello

> 2. suppress any further function call for `x` amount of time

> 3. make function callable again.

You can really think about it as *rate limiting* for function calls...

```js
const throttle = (ms, fn) => {
  let scheduler;
  
  return (...args) => {
    if (scheduler) {
      return null;
    }

    fn(...args);
    

    scheduler = setTimeout(
      () => {
        scheduler = null;
      },
      ms
    );
  }
}

const logger = throttle(
  500,
  console.log, 
);

logger('Ciao');

// this is not called
logger('Bello');
logger('Bello');
logger('Bello');
logger('Bello');
logger('Bello');
logger('Bello');

setTimeout(() => logger('Ciao Bello'), 600, 'Ciao Bello');
```

---

1. You can learn about the `arguments` variable at this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), it's a variable that is created and old the function's call... it is largely not recommended anymore since you can use the [array spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) instead.
2. You might also want to learn about [debouncing](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/debouncing-in-javascript/#:%7E:text=Debouncing%20in%20JavaScript%20is%20a,is%20a%20single%20threaded%20language.)